# Difference between array and array stack?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, stack

I was asked this in class but we ran out of time and I can't seem to find anything comprehensive on the interweb.  If i initialize an array with the brackets how does that differ from creating a stack class of array?

With the stack am I actually initializing an array as typically done as in int array[5] {1,2,3,4,5} or am I just initializing a pointer to some space in memory, storing some data there, and using the member functions of stack to operate and manipulate the data?

```
class IntStack
{
public:
   IntStack(int num) {  top = 0; maxelem = num; s = new int[maxelem]; }
   void  push(int t)
   {
      if (top == maxelem) return;
      s[top++] = t;
   }
   int pop()
   {
      if (top == 0) return -1;
      return s[--top];
   }
   void display()
   {
     if (top == 0) { cout << "(empty)\n";  return; }
     for (int t=0 ; t < top ; t++) cout << s[t] << " ";
     cout << "\n";
   }
   int   empty()  {  return top == 0;  }
private:
   int *s;
   int top;
   int maxelem;
```

That is the code we had written down. I'm trying to understand stack using array implementation and the different to the array container.

edit:

This was figured out and it was my confusion in the course at the time.  the professor was trying to show us how STL containers were implemented by having us create our own, and the question was specific to the classroom in that we created our own "stack" using an array.  A stack is a LIFO structure and this was a question on a test that asked us to discern the difference between the c++ array and the "array stack" we had created in class.  I had misunderstood at the time of this question and thought array stack was something of a C++ standard.

I am trying to bring up my score on SO so I can post another question and am not sure if i should delete questions or edit them to get in better standing.

Comment: What do you mean by "a stack class of array"? Can you give an example of each?

Comment: These terms sound like they're specific to your classroom. You might want to ask your professor to clarify outside of class, or else bring it up at the start of your next class.

Comment: More context is needed. I second Kevin's question.

I don't know that this question can be answered as-is.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I edited the question.  I meant more so how the stack using array implementation differs from using std::array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the C++ standard library you have std::vector, std::stack, std::deque and std::array. All of them are "array like" containers, but they serve different use-cases. You also have the native array inherited from C, but usually you will not want to use that.

This is one (among several) good online references for C++: [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com) [edited]

```
int array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

This will reserve a memory-buffer for 5 integers, using a "C" array. With C++11 and later, you would almost always want to use std::array in stead since this gives you access to iterators and container methods, - and allows you to use your array in standard algorithms.

Comment: The site you linked to is terrible and full of mistakes

Comment: As a more constructive piece of feedback, the website `cppreference.com` is generally considered to be a high-quality reference site for C++, while `cplusplus.com` has historically had a lot of errors and incorrect information in it. Going forward, I'd recommend using cppreference.

Comment: I stand corrected. (Usually I randomly end up using either when I need to know exactly how something works - but you are right,  cppreference.com is the better one).